# Selecting ten top categories based on a columnt in another table with eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables: `uploads`, `categories` and a `many-to-many` table called `category_upload`.

The tables look like this :

```
**categories**

id
name

**uploads**

id
name
downloads(integer)

**category_upload**

id
category_id
upload_id
```

Every time I download an "Upload" the value in the downloads column is increased by 1.

What I want to do, but couldn't figure out how to even start is to select top 10 categories based on the `downloads` column in the `uploads` table. So, if the total of the `downloads` column is the biggest for all uploads from a given category this category should be number one and so on to number ten.

Can this be achieved with eloquent or just SQL and how? Any tips are appreciated!

Here is how I've set up my relationships in the models :

Category :

```
public function uploads(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Upload');
    }
```

Upload :

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  What is a "book" for instance?

Comment: @GordonLinoff book is an upload, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select category_id, uploads
From (
    Select category_id, SUM(downloads) as uploads
    From uploads as u
    Left join upload_category as uc on uc.id=u.upload_id
    Left join category as c on c.id=uc.category_id
    Group by  category_id    )as t
  Order by uploads desc
  Limit 10
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It worked with some minor tweaks, here's what I changed : Select name, uploads
            From (
            Select c.name, SUM(downloads) as uploads
            From uploads as u
            INNER join category_upload as uc on uc.upload_id=u.id
            INNER join categories as c on c.id=uc.category_id
            Group by  c.name    )as t
            Order by uploads desc
             Limit 10

Answer (score 0):

your `Category` model

```
public function downloads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Upload','category_upload','category_id','upload_id');
}
```

In your controller(`Catagory`)

try this

```
Category::select("*")->with(['downloads' => function($q){
    $q->oderBy('downloades','desc')->take(10)->get();
})
```